# UIImageVIew.image isn't be changed

Tags: ios, image, swift, uiimageview

I'm newbie to iOS programming, and trying to developer "FoodTracker" in [Swift tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW1). Below is all my code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    //MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var mealNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        nameTextField.delegate = self

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    //MARK: Actions
    @IBAction func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        // Hide the keyboard.
        nameTextField.resignFirstResponder()

        //UIImagePickerController is a view controller that lets a user pick media from their photo library.
        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

        //Only allow photos to be picked, not taken.
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

        //Make sure ViewController is notified when the user picks an image.
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    @IBAction func setDefaultLabelText(sender: UIButton) {
        mealNameLabel.text = "Default Text"
    }

    //MARK: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        //Dismiss the picker if the user canceled.
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }


    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithinfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        //The info dictionary contains multiple representations of the image, and this uses the original.
        let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        photoImageView.image = selectedImage
        // Dismiss the picker.
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    //MARK: UITextFieldDelegate
    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        //hide the keyboard.
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true

    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        mealNameLabel.text = textField.text

    }
}
```

The app is executed normally but the image can't be changed.
The normal process is click the image > select any image from Camera roll > change the image of idle screen. The problem is last step, "change the image of idle screen."
Which point is my mistake? I have compared my code with example code in tutorial again and again, but I couldn't find something helpful. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

2 things:
First declare the

```
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController();
```

as an instance variable and then set it's delegate to self in viewdidload

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad();
    imagePicker.delegate=self;
}
```

This way it's set only once (rather reseting for each func call)

Second I suggest to use :

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
photoImageView.image=image;
 }
```

instead of (didFinishPickingMediaWithinfo ...), which made exactly for picking image, just as you need and you don't need casting.

Here is a simplified example:

[image picker example](http://pastebin.com/qFKKhwfX)

Hope it helped

Comment: Thank for your help but while tracking your reply, my code entirly mess up. At now, the camera roll isn't pulled up. I can't figure out what the reason is. And I don't know what I should ask. I think I should follow whole course from start. If I become able to change the image, I'll comment on this question. Anyway thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly, I figure out the solution. But it's little trivial.
The problem is Language version. I used XCode 6.4 and Swift 1.2.
But the homepage used XCode 7.0 beta and Swift 2.0.
This is the reason of my problem. And now, all works fine.
Thank you for all my responders.

Answer (score -1):

Did you look at selectedImage variable? Does it nil? Try to setup breakpoint to line after setting selectedImage.

Comment: Oh, breakpoint? I didn't think about that. That may be a good choice but it's too late. :-( In spite of this, it is very good idea for me. I'll apply this skill in next time. Thank you so much~